# How to make multi spannable text?

Tags: android, html

This is example.

```
String source = "This is example text";
Spannable out = new SpannedString(source);
StyleSpan boldSpan = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);
out.setSpan(boldSpan, 1, 3, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
out.setSpan(boldSpan, 9, 12, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

//someTextView.setText(out);
```

Expected result: T**hi**s is e**xam**ple text ("hi" & "xam" are bold)

Actual result:      This is e**xam**ple text (works only last setSpan method and bold is only "xam")

How to make multi spannable text? It's possible?

Maybe problem is in *Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE* flag? Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think you need a **new StyleSpan for each.**

```
String source = "This is example text";
Spannable out = new SpannedString(source);
StyleSpan boldSpan = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);
StyleSpan boldSpan2 = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);
out.setSpan(boldSpan, 1, 3, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
out.setSpan(boldSpan2, 9, 12, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Haven't tried it out though.

Comment: No problem. Glad to hear it. :) Accept the answer please if you're happy with my solution.

Comment: I've not got to this problem yet, I was just happily looking through the questions.. But this would have stumped me too.

Comment: **"new StyleSpan for each"**

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that each bold spannable text must be represented by a `StyleSpan`. The reason for yours is just the same as reassignment of a value.